# Remove last character from regex match

Tags: regex

I have strings that are concatenations of airline codes/flightnumbers, separated with `;`. The airline code and flight number are either separated by a space  or `-`. So some examples are:

```
AA-1234;UA 243;EK 23;
9W 23;B6-134
```

Now I want to grab the airline codes from this.

I came up with the following regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[ -]`. This works to grab the airline codes but also includes the airlinecode-flightnumber separator. How would I adjust my regex to not include this?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}(?=[ -])` or `([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})[ -]`

Answer (score 1):

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}(?=[ -])`

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/inceJ2/1)